# corrupted file name when uploading non-latin file name using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, http-post

I am using HttpWebRequest to upload files to an HttpServlet running on tomcat, if the file name contains non-Latin characters the uploaded file on the server has corrupted characters.

this is my file upload method:

```
    public static void HttpUploadFileEx(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc, WebHeaderCollection collection, NetworkCredential networkCredential)
    {
        log.Debug(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        wr.Credentials = networkCredential;
        wr.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
        foreach (string s in collection)
        {
            wr.Headers[s] = collection[s];
        }


        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }
        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, Path.GetFileName(file), contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            log.Debug(string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error uploading file", ex);
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

What do I need to change to support non-Latin file names ?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't with a character set on the server?   verify that IIS can handle non-latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing:

wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

to

wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + boundary;